# IN SSISDB not able to create new folder

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

While I'm creating a folder in Integration service catalog - SSISDB i'm getting an error as below,

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Operation 'Create' on object 'CatalogFolder[@Name='dev']' failed during execution. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.3000.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).121019-1325+)&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65536. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error: 
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. An error relating to security occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A)
System.IO.FileLoadException: 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)

Cannot find the folder 'dev' because it does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10314)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.5058&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=10314&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I have tried while Deploying the package in SSIS I'm getting the same error.

Why am I getting this error? Is there any way to create folder in SSISDB?

Answer (score 4):

This error could occur when you change the database owner (`db_owner`) or the db was moved to another server. These are possible reasons.

Run this script and try again:

```
ALTER DATABASE SSISDB SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

Comment: Using SQL Server 2012 I tried this method and unfortunately it did not work. Does the server require a restart after this operation?